# Can't copy inputted text in a textarea while using Chrome

Tags: textarea

I've created a simple HTML form with textarea's, in IE I can 'select all' and it will copy all of the info on the page AND in the textarea's, but in Chrome, it won't copy the info in the textarea's. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<textarea rows="3" cols="60">user inputs data here, won't copy this while using Chrome</textarea>
```

Comment: Do you mean `right click`->`select all`? I don't see a `select all` in chrome except in a textarea/input. `Ctrl+A`->`Ctrl+C` gives you the text on the whole page including `textarea` on Chrome 20

Answer (score 0):

You could consider this as a bug. Report bugs here:

http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

As workaround you could use javascript to extract the textarea text. Or File -> Save As will preserve the textarea contents.